# Radiobuttons instead of dropdownlist in mvc 3 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, radio-button, editorfor

I have a View where the model has a collection of items. Then I have an EditorFor template that takes care of creating a dropdownlist for the user to select one of a limited number of values for each item in the collection:

```
@model Consultants.Models.ProgramSkill
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Program.Name
    </td>
        <td>@Model.Program.Category
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Level, new SelectList(new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, Model.Level))
    </td>
</tr>
```

But I would rather have radiobuttons to do the same thing, is that possible in MVC 3? If so, how?

Answer (score 20):

That would be a perfect candidate for a custom html helper:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> values)
    {
        string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(ex);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        int counter = 1;
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            sb.Append(htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(ex, item.Value, new { id = name + counter.ToString()}));
            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.SetInnerText(item.Text);
            label.Attributes.Add("for", name + counter.ToString());
            sb.Append(label.ToString());
            counter++;
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Level = "2",
            Items = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ToString(), 
                Text = "item " + x
            })
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButtonListFor(x => x.Level, Model.Items)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: I modified the above RadioButtonFor() method to allow pre-selecting a radio button item (this is simply a matter of setting the checked attribute):                              sb.Append(htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(ex, item.Value, (item.Selected ? new { Checked = "" } : null)));

Answer (score 8):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Level, 0)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Level, 1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Level, 2)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Level, 3)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Level, 4)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Level, 5)
```

or with a simple loop:

```
@for(int level = 0; level <= 5; level++)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Level, level)
}
```

Comment: But with this, how do I set the currently selected Level? (As I do with the dropdownlist)

Comment: If Level is an int it will be selected automatically using RadioButtonFor